# Lua: Chunk? Block? End?

Tags: lua

[image: Which is chunk? which is block?]

I am not grasping the chunk or block concept. I have searched online, but people use explanations I don’t fully understand yet, from my result searches, no one uses pictures to provide a visual to their walls of text.

That’s why I included a img in my post. I annotated to the image to show what I am trying to find out.

Which is Block? which is chunk?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please see [why not upload images of code when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). Thanks.

Comment: [Chunk](https://www.lua.org/pil/1.1.html) is the whole source text (the whole file).  [Block](https://www.lua.org/pil/4.2.html) is a sequence of statements inside outer (if/do/while/for/...) statement, block is usually indented in the source text.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Thank you. So basically in my image, the yellow circle is the block. Thank you. That clears things up a lot.